# Early morning on-demand taxi in Barcelona, Spain

Tags: airport-transfer, taxis, barcelona

I need to go to the airport in early in the morning so I'm looking for popular on-demand taxi services in Spain.

- My Airbnb : El Born, Barcelona
- From : Barcelona Airport
- To : Geneva Airport
- Time of departure : 8:40AM

Will taxi be a best way, or any other idea?

Comment: I was about to suggest Uber, but looks like they've been forced to pull out of Spain for now: http://skift.com/2015/04/30/why-ubers-one-size-fits-all-approach-didnt-work-in-spain/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a lot of mobile apps to book a taxi in advance in Barcelona, you can use [mytaxi](https://itunes.apple.com/es/app/mytaxi-la-taxi-app/id357852748), [PideTaxi](http://www.applesfera.com/redirect?url=https%3A%2F%2Fitunes.apple.com%2Fes%2Fapp%2Fpidetaxi%2Fid737441460) (I've used this one and I recommend it, this is the official app of the spanish radio taxi association) or [Joinup taxi](http://www.applesfera.com/redirect?url=https%3A%2F%2Fitunes.apple.com%2Fes%2Fapp%2Fjoinup-taxi-pasajero%2Fid554668455). I linked iOS links but there are also versions for Android.

Besides, if you look for a cheaper option, you can take a train. The *[Rodalies](http://www.renfe.com/GA/viajeros/cercanias/barcelona/)* service opens at 5:00. The closest station to your location should be **Estació de França** and from there you can take a train to **Barcelona Sants** and there take one to the airport. It takes around 55 minutes to get to the airport from França. Also, as fedorqui mentions in his comment, you can consider the *[Aerobús](http://www.aerobusbcn.com/en/timetable)* which departures from **Plaza Catalunya** every 5-10 minutes (the first one at 5:00) and costs 5.90€.

Comment: May be also interesting to mention the [Aerobús](http://www.aerobusbcn.com/).

Comment: @fedorqui Thanks, I had completely forgotten about it, I have edited my answer.

Comment: Note I mentioned Aerobús because it goes directly to either terminal 1 or 2, whereas the train arrives to terminal 2 and then you need a shuttle bus to reach terminal 1. This sometimes leads to confusion!

Comment: Can tickets for the aerobus be bought in the bus or do I have to get them in advance?